# Removing Duplicate Tuple Pairs by Condition

Tags: python, numpy

How do you remove duplicate tuples from a list based on the condition that if `(Y, Z)` and `(Z, Y)` are part of the list, then we only keep the match where `Y < Z`?

For example, if we start with the following list of Car ID pairs:

```
CarID1 = [(100, 500), (100, 600), (100, 700), (500, 100), (500, 200)],
```

then we should remove the `(500, 100` entry and end up with:

```
CarID2 = [(100, 500), (100, 600), (100, 700), (500, 200)]
```

I tried the following code to grab unique tuples, but it did not do what I described.

```
y = np.unique(x, axis=0)
z = [] 
for i in y:
   z.append(tuple(i))
```

Comment: Are the existing tuples unique, or might you have, say 3 copies of `(100, 700)`?

Comment: The existing tuples are unique.  Would the code change based upon whether the tuples are unique or not?

Comment: It would, if you wanted to eliminate the duplicates.  Start with the answer I gave, @wim's comment, and see what you can do (i.e. exercise for the student).

Comment: If you're trying to maintain a list of unique elements, [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) may be worth looking into.

Comment: Does order of the results matter?

Answer (score 3):

Using a dictionary you can do it in linear time.
Note that for each tuple `(u,v)` I first check if `(v,u)` already exists and in that case I keep the one with `u < v`, otherwise it is inserted in the dictionary.

```
CarID1 = [(100, 500), (100, 600), (100, 700), (500, 100), (500, 200)]

d ={}
for (u, v) in CarID1:
    if (v, u) in d:
        d[(v,u)] = (u,v) if u < v else (v,u)
    else:
        d[(u,v)]  = (u,v)

d.values()
#dict_values([(100, 500), (100, 600), (100, 700), (500, 200)])
```

Comment: This may change the order of the tuples in the resulting list since the key loose order in Python dicts before 3.6

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
[(y, z) for y, z in CarID1 if (z, y) not in CarID1 or y < z]
```

And if an O(n) runtime is important, then use a set, which will take care of duplicates as well but may not guarantee the same order:

```
CarID1_distinct = set(CarID1)
[(y, z) for y, z in CarID1 if (z, y) not in CarID1_distinct or y < z]
```

Comment: You're creating the set on every iteration of the comprehension

Answer (score 0):

```
z = [(a, b) for a, b in carID1 if not ( (b, a) in CarID1 and b > a) ]
```

This is a list comprehension that considers all pairs (a, b) in your original list.  It keeps them all *except* where the reversed pair is also in the list, and the elements are in the order you don't want.

Output:

```
>>> z
[(100, 600), (100, 700), (500, 100), (500, 200)]
```

Comment: It's O(n**2) .. this should be O(n)